# How to use features from Geojson in openlayers3?

Tags: openlayers-3, geojson

I am using openlayers3 and i want to bring my features from feature.json, it seems when my map is loded I can get the feature file from network as xhr request but i am not able to see my polygons on map. Here below is my code

```
function showMap() {
  var vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
    projection: 'EPSG:5650',
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
      projection: 'EPSG:5650',
      url: 'feature.json'
    })
  });
  var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'tilemap',
    controls: ol.control.defaults({
      attributionOptions: /** @type {olx.control.AttributionOptions} */ ({
       collapsible: false
      })
    }),
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Image({
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
          url: 'http://www.geodaten-mv.de/dienste/adv_dop',
          crossOrigin: null,
          projection: 'EPSG:5650',
          params: {
            VERSION: '1.3.0',
            LAYERS: 'mv_dop',
            FORMAT: 'image/jpeg',
            CRS: 'EPSG:5650'
          }
        })
      }),vector
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
      projection: 'EPSG:5650',
      center: [33355494, 5983295],
      zoom: 10
    })
  });
  DisplayTilesServices.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: There's a little diff between a JSON file and a GeoJSON file. Is your `feature.json` a valid GeoJSON file?

Comment: I found the solution, I was using olderversion of openlayers and now instead of Using url in source, i am using features and it works!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using olderversion of openlayers and now instead of Using url in source, now I am using features and it works!! see the code below

```
 $http.get('feature.geojson').then(function(res){
    var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
    source=new ol.source.Vector({
      projection: 'EPSG:5650',
      features:format.readFeatures(res.data)
    });
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
      source: source
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
  },function(){})
```